# Yii2 Shopping cart -- Interface 'backend\models\CartPositionInterface' not found

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions

I have problem when using [yii shopping cart](https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart). This is the my model

```
<?php 
namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yz\shoppingcart;

class Products extends ActiveRecord implements CartPositionInterface
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the namespace full path to CartPositionInterface

```
use path_to_file\CartPositionInterface;
```

or

```
implements \path_to_file\CartPositionInterface
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me